# How to get rid of this noise?

Tags: noise-reduction

im making a 3D animation of two glass hands cracking, but as Im getting to the point of sorting the lighting for the scene my glass material is giving off a large rectangle of noise. Im using evee engine btw.

[image]

Comment: Hello Charlie! Could you upload your file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com, and [edit your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/198550/edit) accordingly?

Comment: Ive solved it! Volumetric lighting drop off was at 600 meters